# Single Perturbation inner approximation characteristic equation.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, perturbation-theory

I'm given $\epsilon y'=y=e^{-t}$. I went through and found the outer approximation and then proceeded to find the inner approx. I rescaled and balanced the equation to get:
$Y'+Y=e^{- \tau\epsilon}$ where I've defined $\tau=\frac{t}{\delta(\epsilon)}$

My book shows that this is: $Y'+Y=1$  and then somehow gets to the solution being $Y_i(\tau)= 1+Ce^{{t}/{\epsilon}}$

I can't seem to figure out how they got that. If the assumption holds that $\epsilon=0$, than how does the characteristic polynomial $r+1=1$ yield that $Y_i(\tau)$?

Comment: Is your equation $\epsilon y'+y=e^{-t}$?

Comment: The outer approximation should just be $y_0=e^{-t}$, $y_1=e^{-t}-y_0'$. The inner approximation is where you rescale $t$. Do you know the layer should be at $t=0$? They will have written the exponential as a Taylor series in powers of $\epsilon$ and truncated appropriately, as you write your equation as a powers series in $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in the characteristic polynomial. It needs to be set equal to $0$ and then solve for the homogeneous. From there you calculate the particular solution using an integrating factor. The answer is fairly easy from there. $y_p=1$ and $y_h=e^{-\tau}$